# How to extract specific data from PDF documents using Apache Tika

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika

I am attempting to use `Apache Tika™` to extract the following information from `PDF` documents

1. List of Authors (Not just the lead Author)
2. The document Abstract.
3. All associated document Identifiers, e.g. DOI, ISBN, ISSN, PUI etc
4. Document Headings and Sub headings
5. Document images
6. List of citations

For the above list I could imagine its only "3)." that I will need to employ "other" resources to obtain all document Id's as from what I can see you cannot rely on the PDF document itself containing all its associated Id's.

for all the other content it must be available "somehow" either by using Tika builtin features or by developing a custom set of handlers and/or parsers.

Is it possible to employ Apache Tike "out Of The Box" to extract the required information?

Comment: Did you try using the [Grobid parser for Apache Tika](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/GrobidJournalParser)? That's normally the best way to get that sort of content-based metadata out of journal articles

Comment: That looks like the solution. Thanks very much for taking the time to respond. I'm building with gradle, can I obtain Grobid in my gradle build?

Comment: Probably best ask on the [Tika users list](http://tika.apache.org/mail-lists.html), then update the wiki page + answer here once you find out how!

Comment: look slike its in Maven central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grobid. so i am good to go!